# Need to call method AFTER accessing data from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am accessing data stored in the firebase realtime database, but after accessing the data, I want to call a method that will set up a view.

```
func fetchPostData(){
    Database.database().reference().child("Posts").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]{
            let post = Posts()
            if let val = dictionary["name"] as? String{
                post.objName = val
            }
            if let val = dictionary["price"] as? String{
                post.objPrice = val
            }
            if let val = dictionary["summary"] as? String{
                post.objSummary = val
            }
            if let val = dictionary["username"] as? String{
                post.postUsername = val
            }
            self.posts.append(post)

        }
        setUpView()

    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

The problem is that like all of the firebase API's, it is asynchronous, so the method will return immediately after being called. But what I want to be able to do is to have the `setUpView()` is called only once, after all the data has been processed and stored. I tried to see if there was a version of this function that had a completionHandler, and unfortunately, it does not exist.

So is there any way that I can have this method be called only once AFTER all the data has been stored?

Please help, I need it!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this

```
func fetchPostData(success:@escaping (Bool) -> Void){
        Database.database().reference().child("Posts").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]{
                /// Let get posts First
                let post = Posts()
                if let val = dictionary["name"] as? String{
                    post.objName = val
                }
                if let val = dictionary["price"] as? String{
                    post.objPrice = val
                }
                if let val = dictionary["summary"] as? String{
                    post.objSummary = val
                }
                if let val = dictionary["username"] as? String{
                    post.postUsername = val
                }
                /// Post Retrieved and added in  array
                self.posts.append(post)
                /// Return this function when you are sure data is retrieved from DB
                success(true)
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)      
    }
```

**Usage**

```
fetchPostData { (success) in
    if success {
        /// You did received bool as yes
        /// Perform required Task
        setUpView()
    }
}
```